# How to filter an index by the maximum value of a field?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

There is a field in the index by the name of date but the data of that field is not in a proper date format its only a number. So I want a filter to include only the data of maximum data of date field I mean how to create a filter which finds the maximum value of the date field and filter the index based upon that value.

Comment: can you share some sample of your data ? if you provide that, I would be able to provide more concrete info.

Comment: My data in that field is like: 20220426, 20220425, 20220526. Is there any to filter that data in the add filter section to select the field and operator for that field to filter or to write an kql query in the search field.

Comment: In that case, its very easy to do with max aggregation, did you try that ? if you face issues, provide me your sample data and expected results

Comment: I will try that but I want to save the query to do filteration for all indexes because all indexes have the same filed only the name of the indexes are different.

Comment: Amit right, you can use max aggregation (and on multi index, if the fieldname is the same it will work like a charm).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [single value max aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-max-aggregation.html) to find the highest number in your date field.